# NSolve and NIntegrate, or a better approach

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I need to define and plot the following function

$$ a(t) := \exp\left(\int Z(t)\; dt\right) $$

where $Z(t)$ is the solution to the equation

$$ 0 = t - 2 \int^Z_1 F(x)\; dx $$

with $F = F(x)$ being a known (but complicated and non-integrable) function.

> How do I define and plot the function $a(t)$ in Mathematica?

Here is my attempt with a particular function $F(x)$ that I need to work with:

```
A = 0;
F[x_] = - ((4*A*x^(9/2) + 64*x^6 - 4*Sqrt[A*x^9*(32*x^(3/2) + A)])^(1/3)/(16*x^4 - 4*x^2*(4*A*x^(9/2) + 64*x^6 - 4*Sqrt[A*x^9*(32*x^(3/2) + A)])^(1/3) - (4*A*x^(9/2) + 64*x^6 - 4*Sqrt[A*x^9*(32*x^(3/2) + A)])^(2/3)));

A = 0;
Int[Z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[F[x], {x, 1, Z}]
S[t_?NumericQ] := NSolve[t - 2*Int[Z] == 0, Z]
a[t_] := Exp[Integrate[S[t], t]]
```

However, when trying to evaluate for example $a(2)$ I get the following error:

[image: The error]

Comment: When you said non-integrable you meant to say that it doesn't have a closed-form expression right?

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

Maybe use `NDSolve`. Here we differential the original equation and get two ODEs.

If we set
$$ a(t)=\exp\left(\int_{0}^tZ(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\right)$$
then $a(0)=1$ and $a'(t)=a(t)Z(t)$

vice versa

```
DSolve[{a'[t] == a[t]*Z[t], a[0] == 1}, a[t], t]
```

$$ a(t)\to \exp \left(\int _0^tZ(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\right)$$

```
A = 0;
F[x_] := -((4*A*x^(9/2) + 64*x^6 - 4*Sqrt[A*x^9*(32*x^(3/2) + A)])^(1/
        3)/(16*x^4 - 
       4*x^2*(4*A*x^(9/2) + 64*x^6 - 
           4*Sqrt[A*x^9*(32*x^(3/2) + A)])^(1/3) - (4*A*x^(9/2) + 
          64*x^6 - 4*Sqrt[A*x^9*(32*x^(3/2) + A)])^(2/3)));
sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == a[t]*Z[t], 1 == 2 F[Z[t]]*Z'[t], a[0] == 1, 
   Z[0] == 1}, {a, Z}, {t, 0, .4}]
Plot[{a[t], Z[t]} /. First[sol] // Evaluate, {t, 0, .4}]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know that `a[0]==1`?

Comment: @yarchik integrating from 0 to 0 gives always 0, no?

Comment: @Yes, right, I have seen you updated your post. The original question is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @yarchik how so?

Comment: @SNC92 Have a look at your definition of $a(t)$, there is an indefinite integral on the rhs, which is defined up to a constant. cvgmt properly writes a definite integral on the rhs, which is uniquely defined.

Comment: @yarchik ok I see, thanks

Comment: @cvgmt thanks for the answer; It is a clever approach